# Udp, How to handle IP-changes?

Tags: c#, .net, udp, ip-address

How does the .Net UdpClient handle IP-changes?
Lets for instance say we have a Udp-server and a Udp-client thats connected to the server, they both communicate back and forth... however.. all of a sudden the server (or the client) changes IP.. how is this handled?.. is it handled at all?

Or to put the whole thing in perspective.. lets say we have a gamer hosting a listening server, a bunch of people are connected to the server.. and all of a sudden the server changes IP..wouldn't that result in a connection-loss for all the connected players? How do you prevent this?

Comment: what do you mean by "all of a sudden the server changes IP"?

Comment: UDP does not use connections in the same way TCP does - it works by sending fire-and-forget datagrams. If you transmit to an address that is no longer valid, nothing will happen.

Comment: For instance if the ISP gives the person hosting the server a new ip, or maybe this is a scenario that simply doesnt happen. With the risk of exposing my poor knowledge of networks, is there any chance of the server changing its ip provided that the server doesnt lose its power or connection to the router? (This question might belong to a different exchange-forum..sorry if thats the case)

Comment: Use the Name of the Server instead of the IP.  Often in corporate networks the IP address of a PC will change periodically (usually 3-4 weeks) so using the Name of the server which doesn't change rather than the IP address will solve issue.  The Net library will accept either an ip or computer name when constructing the UdpClient.

Comment: Ah, thats great news!
But just for the sake of... of the sake...
What if the server isnt hosted on the "LAN"?

Comment: @jdweng Yes that's what I did some years back. If you host a service on-line the ISP will give you a fixed IP address.  Some routers will block UDP broadcasts.  You are better off using TCP/IP instead and having a known server address.  This could then route you connections via other TCP/IP connections.  If you are hosting this server from somewhere with a dynamic IP (i.e changing IP) then use a domain name.  Have a look at http://www.noip.com.

Comment: @James sadly I cant use a TCP/IP since in my case im about to get started developing a game-server.. which then requires the speed of Udp from what I have read from multiple sites and places

Comment: James : Only Multicast udp usually get blocked.  Non-Multicast udp connects exactly the same as tcp.  The only differences between tcp and udp is tcp is reliable and every message is achnowleded while udp sends blind (no ack).

Comment: @jdweng Ok good point.  Using a domain name is still the best option in this case though but the clients would have to poll to look for a change to the IP allocation as well as the server polling to post up the new IP to a service such as noip.com.

Comment: @lnx51 No problem, I understand.